# How to return different array values according to condition?

Tags: java, arrays, return

I'm trying to return different array values according to the condition. Here is my code but it made error. Please help me find out what's the problem.

```
private static String subject[] = {"Mathematics", "English"};
private static String studentNum[] = {"1", "2"};
private static int marks[][] = {{56,51},   // Student 1 mark for Mathermatics
                                {69,85}};  // Student 2 mark for English

public static double AverageMarks(String aCode) {

    double sum[] = new double[subject.length];
    double average[] = new double[subject.length];

    for(int j=0;j<subject.length;j++) {
        for(int i=0;i<studentNum.length;i++) {
            sum[j] += marks[j][i];
            average[j] = (sum[j] / studentNum.length); // average[0] is the average mark of Mathermatics and average[1] is the average mark of English
        }

        if (aCode.equals(subject[j])) {
            return average[j];
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: you need to tell us more details about the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. The line

```
average[j] = (sum[j] / studentNum.length);
```

should be out of the nested `for`, because the nested `for` is used to sum every grade, after it finishes you should assign the sum to `sum[j]`.

Also, you should put the `return 0` at the end of the function, or the `for` loop would just loop one time (because if the condition `aCode.equals(...)` is not true, it will `return 0`) in the first loop.

```
public static double averageMarks(String aCode)
{
    double sum[] = new double[subject.length];
    double average[] = new double[subject.length];

    for (int j = 0; j < subject.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < studentNum.length; i++) {
            sum[j] += marks[j][i];

        }
        average[j] = (sum[j] / studentNum.length); // average[0] is the average mark of Mathermatics and average[1] is the average mark of English

        if (aCode.equals(subject[j])) {
            return average[j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** I would recommend you to follow Java naming conventions. Your method should be called like `methodName`, not like `MethodName`.

Answer (score 0):

My initial look, I notice this since you didn't describe more about your error I layout the first thing i see that could be wrong.

```
if (aCode.equals(subject[j])) {return average[j];}
    else {return 0;}
```

This line of code in particular i believe is wrong. It'll never get to the outer loop to check the different subject because it goes straight to the `else.`

```
public static double AverageMarks(String aCode) {

    double sum[] = new double[subject.length];
    double average[] = new double[subject.length];

    for(int j=0;j<subject.length;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<studentNum.length;i++) {
            sum[j] += marks[j][i];
         }
        average[j] = (sum[j] / studentNum.length);
        if (aCode.equals(subject[j])) return average[j];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having dead code in the program.

```
for(int j=0;j<subject.length;j++)
```

These `loop` is of no use because in the first iteration of the loop you are using `return`.

Also one `return` type of the method is missing which must be outside the 2 loops.